# Grails why is my cache getting invalidated?

Tags: caching, grails, grails-orm

I have cached some domain instances and queries in my grails application. I would expect that after the first time the queries are fired to db, the subsequent calls will only hit cache. 
But, I am seeing that periodically the queries hit db (after every 5-6 times). No data is getting updated/inserted into database in the mean time. I am using p6spy to check out all the queries that are logged and do not see any updates or inserts happening.

Is there any additional settings I need to tweek?

Currently domain class has

```
static mapping = {
cach true
}
```

Queries like `findBy*` have the `[cache:true]` set.

Comment: This is normal. the cache will be invalidated after certain conditions are met. configuration of the cache should be set in the ehcache config. by default there is a ehcache-failsafe config that is loaded. And i think cache is invalidated after 5 minutes by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't configure Ehcache, your caches will use the default timeout of 120 seconds. See http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xml for a well-commented example file that's the same as the default file that's in the Ehcache jar.

You can configure timeouts, max elements in memory, whether to spill over to disk, etc. by creating an ehcache.xml in your application. Put it in src/java and it will be copied into the classpath, and Ehcache will see it and use yours instead of its defaults.

Comment: I stumbled upon the following post(http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/07/10/hibernate-query-cache/) regarding hibernate query cache. Are these observations still valid, meaning is it better that I turn off the query cache alltogether?

Comment: Yes, the points are all still valid. Some queries are good candidates for caching, but if you're editing, adding, or deleting instances of a particular domain class it's best to not cache queries for that class. Cache instances and queries for read-only and read-mostly domain classes, and for ones that are updated, consider avoiding it (depends on the app and use cases though). I do recommend that you change `grails.hibernate.cache.queries` to false in `Config.groovy` and add `cache: true` on a per-query basis.

Comment: Thanks! I was under impression that turning off the grails.hibernate.cache.queries to false meant that no queries could be cached. This flexibility of turning it off and then ability to set cache:true for individual queries is very good.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Is `hibernate{cache.use_query_cache=false}` in `DataSource.groovy` same as `grails.hibernate.cache.queries=false` in `Config.groovy`?

Comment: No, `use_query_cache` turns the feature on/off, but think of `grails.hibernate.cache.queries` as auto-cache queries, i.e. always use it for every query - a _very_ bad idea - see http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/07/10/hibernate-query-cache/